# Depth map values in opencv's reprojectImageTo3D()

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

OpenCV's reprojectImageTo3D() outputs a *"3-channel image representing a 3D surface"*.
You can access this data by

```
Vec3f coordinates = _3dImage.at<Vec3f>(y,x);
float depth = _3dImage.at<Vec3f>(y,x)[2];
```

witch returns a vector [X,Y,Z].

In *"Learning OpenCV"* by Gary Bradski & Adrian Kaehler, it is explained that the depth is calculated by

Z = f T / (x_left - x_right)

where f = focal length, T = eye base/translation between cameras, (x_left - x_right) = disparity

This exact formula is implemented in OpenCV (I checked the source code - however there is for some reason an additional negative sign). The question is: **In which unit are the X, Y, Z values specified?**

T is in your unit (e.g. mm), x_l - x_r is in pixel and **[ f ] = ?**

When you calibrate the camera, you specify the chessboard's size in real world units (e.g. mm). Does the intrinsic matrix therefore have real world units? Or is it specified in px? Unfortunately I cannot find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying equation that performs depth reconstruction is:

`Z = fB/d`, where

- `f` is the focal length (in pixels), you called it as eye base/translation between cameras
- `B` is the stereo baseline (in meters)
- `d` is disparity (in pixels) that measures the difference in retinal position between corresponding points
- `Z` is the distance along the camera Z axis

The 3D position `(X,Y,Z)` of an image point (e.g. `(u,v)` in pixels) can be given in meters, cm, mm or whatever you choose, because the 3D coordinates `(X,Y,Z)` are in the same units as the chessboard's square size. For example, if you define the square size to be 1 cm then the 3D coordinates will be in cm as well.

i.e.:

```
Size boardSize(4, 5); // 4x5 chessboard
float squareSize = 0.025F; // 0.025 meters
for( int i = 0; i < boardSize.height; i++ )
    for( int j = 0; j < boardSize.width; j++ )
        corners.push_back(Point3f(float(j*squareSize), float(i*squareSize), 0.0F));
```

p.s.:
After `Z` is determined, `X` and `Y` can be calculated using the usual projective camera equations:

- `X = uZ/f`
- `Y = vZ/f`

Comment: The baseline (in your post `B`, in my question `T`) always has to be given in meters. The unit is solely defined by the size of the calibration pattern? So this information must be stored in the `c_x, c_y` values of the intrinsic matrix.

Comment: Yes, it is defined by the size of pattern. So, the unity measure of `Z` (i.e. mm) stands for whatever unit of measure one chooses for the chessboard pattern.

Comment: But this information shouldn't be stored in the intrinsics matrix, because intrinsics does not depend on the scene viewed. This information stored in the extrinsic parameters which denote the coordinate system transformations from 3D world coordinates to 3D camera coordinates.

Comment: I did not stereo-calibrate the cameras, I only calibrated them. Therefore I only have the camera's intrinsics and provide the extrinsic parameter `T` or `B` by hand. Consequently this is the absolute value and not `X * squareSize`

Comment: You should stereo calibrate them if you can. Otherwise you have to stereo rectify the image pair by the (intrinsics and) provided extrinsics, compute the disparity map and then reproject it to 3D. [Here](http://p.blog.csdn.net/images/p_blog_csdn_net/chenyusiyuan/590931/o_Q_matrix_2.jpg) you can see the form of Q matrix (it consists of translation, principal point and focal length).

Comment: And in this case the unity measure will be the unit of `T` or `B` what you provide by hand.

Comment: Yes you should always stereo-calibrate your rig! Unfortunately I indeed do not have this option. It causes me a lot of sleepless nights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783840/find-fundamental-matrix-with-uncalibrated-stereo-camera